# Changing global font

Tags: html, css, fonts

Alright so I have a font that I use for absolutely everything on my page (besides the logo)

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}
```

Now I want to apply a different font on another piece of text but its not replacing the original one

```
<h1 style='font-family: "Aref Ruqaa", serif;'>Logo Text</h1>
```

TLDR: How do I make it apply a different font on that H1? I tried using font-family initial and then setting a different font but nothing works out.

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BQOaXo

Comment: can you share a jsbin or codepen with this example

Comment: Here you go http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BQOaXo

Comment: The inline styling overrides the global properties though: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/e0d8my79/171/

Comment: @TomislavNikolic your css has


h1 { /* This is not working.. It still uses Trillium for H1 */
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aref+Ruqaa" rel="stylesheet">
}

are you sure you want this and not 


h1 { /* This is not working.. It still uses Trillium for H1 */
font-family: "Aref Ruqaa", serif;
}

.. second case solved your problem

Comment: Heck, even a non inline style declaration overrides the global properties too. CSS styling preference is based on specificity. Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/e0d8my79/172/

Comment: It was a typo on the codepen by me, I am using the font itself inside the H1 external CSS but still nothing. I corrected the typo just now. It simply doesnt work if I add font-family in external CSS or inline or anything.

Comment: @TomislavNikolic Off topic, but why did you delete your other question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41109262/dropping-divs-inside-html ? I was just typing up the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add classes to the html** elements and **make sure those classes load after you global font**.

Avoid inline styling.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Yrsa';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Yrsa'), local('Yrsa-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/yrsa/v1/HvXbkSMs7hgg2r-HiCNOmA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Indie Flower';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Indie Flower'), local('IndieFlower'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/indieflower/v8/10JVD_humAd5zP2yrFqw6ugdm0LZdjqr5-oayXSOefg.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
body {
  background: #111;
  color: #999;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 10%
}
* {
  font-family: 'Yrsa';
}
.other {
  font-family: 'Indie Flower';
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <h1>This is a Header 1 in font A</h1>
    <h1 class="other">This is a Header 1 in font B</h1>
    <h2>This is a Header 2 in font A</h2>
    <h2 class="other">This is a Header 2 in font B</h2>
    <h3>This is a Header 2 in font A</h3>
    <h3 class="other">This is a Header 2 in font B</h3>
    <p>This is a paragraph using font A
      <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in eam simul nostrud definiebas, mea iusto placerat prodesset ei. Eum summo audiam ea. Vitae aperiri at duo. Vis atomorum partiendo id, nam ea noluisse platonem. Nec minimum consequat cu, pri in harum moderatius. Ferri
      aperiam forensibus an nam.</p>
    <p class="other">This is a paragraph using font B
      <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in eam simul nostrud definiebas, mea iusto placerat prodesset ei. Eum summo audiam ea. Vitae aperiri at duo. Vis atomorum partiendo id, nam ea noluisse platonem. Nec minimum consequat cu, pri in harum moderatius. Ferri
      aperiam forensibus an nam.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yeeep thats the one I am looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use this in the CSS:

```
h1{
  font-family: 'Aref Ruqaa', sans-serif;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mOGybb

Answer (score 0):

I think you change the global font, you use this syntax the in css file:

> h1 {    font-family: Aref Ruqaa, sans-serif; }